# Why won't Opera (11.00) display custom (@font-face) fonts?

Tags: css, opera, font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PFDinMonoBold';
    src: url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'),
        url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.otf') format('opentype'),
        url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.svg#webfontS2rh8Zow') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

*made it with the font squirrel generator.*

By the way, custom fonts are not shown on the squirrel web either

What could be the problem?

P.S font work fine in ff,chrome,ie

Comment: Could you put the font somewhere so we can see what is inside the file and understand what is breaking. It may be an interesting case. It would also be good to put an example on how you are using the font declaration.

Comment: it doesn't matter what custom font to use. none of them are working. font declaration example:

font-family: PFDinMonoBold

Comment: Webfonts may be discarded if they're malformed/invalid, in such cases there will be an error message in the Opera's Error Console.

Comment: Erik Dahlström, checked the console - no font errors :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use double quotes for font family name.

```
@font-face {
font-family: "PFDinMonoBold";
src: url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.eot');
src: local('☺'),
    url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.otf') format('opentype'),
    url('pfdinmono-bold-webfont.svg#webfontS2rh8Zow') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: +1 for introducing me to FontSquirrel which looks like a pretty awesome cross browser css3 font-face solution...

Comment: Looks like an Opera bug from where I stand. Thank you.