# opera and @font-face

Tags: css, cross-browser, opera, font-face

I have a font that I've incorporated into my site using @font-face. Even though it displays fine in ff/chome/safari, it's having difficulties rendering in Opera.

I'm using Google's font API; this is in my html:

```
<link 
     href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli' 
     rel='stylesheet' 
     type='text/css' >
```

and then my CSS:

```
     /* this is whats in the linked file */
@font-face 
{   font-family: 'Muli';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Muli'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/muli/v2/    kU4XYdV4jtS72BIidPtqyw.woff') format('woff');
        }


    /* this is the css in my site */
body
{   font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
        }
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working: the API says it works with Opera 10.5 and up...

Comment: According to http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introducing-woff-web-open-font-format/ WOFF is only supported from Opera 11.10 and up.

Answer (score 2):

It's `font-weight: bold;` instead of `font-style: bold;`. [font-style](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-style-prop) values are "italic", "oblique" and "normal". [font-weight](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop) can have "bold", "bolder", "lighter", "normal" or the numeric values 100, 200, ..., 900.

Comment: I was wondering why the error only showed up once. I've fixed that, but still no dice it seems... Opera still wont display my sigmas.

Comment: Hmm, I assume it's the reason that DanMan pointed out in his link then, WOFF only being supported from 11.10 on.

Answer (score 0):

It's `font-weight:bold`, not `font-style:bold`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that if you explicitly define `font-weight: 400;` in your font-face declaration, that font-face will only be used for text with exactly that font-weight. I'm not sure if "400" is the same as "normal", which you're asking for in your `body` selector.

That, and I hope there's no whitespace in your actual font URI.

Answer (score 0):

Try double quotes:

```
@font-face 
{   font-family: "Muli";
    ...
```

More infos here: [Why won't Opera (11.00) display custom (@font-face) fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736471/why-wont-opera-11-00-display-custom-font-face-fonts)