# @Font-Face not working in Opera

Tags: fonts, opera, font-face

I hope you'll take some time and help me out with this issue. I'm trying to integrate [this font](http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=blanch) in wordpress theme. And it works just fine FF, Chrome and IE. But I have problem with Opera. The strangest thing is that it loads but looks like file format is broken. I know it loads because while page loads font converts from serif to sans-serif.

I used fontsquirrel and few other converters to create a kit but seems none of them works properly.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Blanch-Caps';
    src: url('<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/font/blanchcaps/blanch_caps.eot');
    src: url('<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/font/blanchcaps/blanch_caps.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/font/blanchcaps/blanch_caps.woff') format('woff'),
         url('<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/font/blanchcaps/blanch_caps.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/font/blanchcaps/blanch_caps.svg#blanch_caps') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.title h3 {
    font-family: 'Blanch-Caps';
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Once again it works just fine in every other browser except Opera. 
I'm using lowercase transform since Blanch doesn't support caps.

I would appreciate any sort of help.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your code? are you using optimizeLegibility in your css? other questions i have could be easily answered with a code source

Comment: +1 - it would be easier to understand this problem with a link..

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Opera bug...you just need to add double quotes:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Blanch-Caps";
    ...
```

More on the problem here: [Why won't Opera (11.00) display custom (@font-face) fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736471/why-wont-opera-11-00-display-custom-font-face-fonts)